# insertRowsAtIndexPaths calling cellForRowAtIndexPath for every row

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to insert a bunch of rows into an empty UITableView in one step using insertRowsAtIndexPaths. (I know that this doesn't sound all that useful, but it's a simplified version of what I really need to do.)

The issue I'm seeing is that after I make the insertRowsAtIndexPaths call, I get cellForRowAtIndexPath calls for every row I inserted, rather than just those that are visible.

That doesn't seem right. And it's pretty much useless to me if it does this.

The only slightly odd other artifact I see is that when I do this, it actually seems to animate the rows into place. This isn't the withRowAnimation, since that's set to none. But it seems there's some sort of higher level animation concept going on here. I had the off-idea that as it animated the rows into place it thought it needed cells for more/all the rows until they got pushed off screen. But I can't turn off this animation without just using reloadData which I'd prefer to avoid.

Generally I have a data set that changes behind the scenes. I can carefully go through and construct the changes to generate data for the insert/delete/reload calls. But I can't limit that to what's on screen since then it doesn't match the data provider.

I figure I must be missing something ... any ideas?

(I am doing this within a beginUpdates/endUpdates pair but that seems to make no difference.)

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  File a bug report: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Can you create a simple project/code that we can test that duplicates the behavior?  Sounds indeed like it may be a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the next step if it's not something known.

Comment: @smparkes once you file a report, please leave a comment here with the bug number. :)

Comment: @Dave DeLong, everyone says that, but on Radar I never can figure out how to reference another bug.  Any idea?  Or just leave the # in the text body?

Comment: @phooze ... not sure what you mean. When you log into BugReporter, you see a list of your open Radars, and the bug number is the one in the left-most column.  If you mean "reference another bug in the one that i'm writing", then simply saying (in the text body) that "this bug is probably related to #123456" is good enough.

Comment: I probably won't get a chance to see if a simple example has the same issue until after WWDC. Maybe I'll snoop around there and see if any of the Apple folks have comments ...

Comment: @Dave, yeah, that's what I meant.  I REALLY don't get why Radar is so terrible. I had 2 clearly reproducible bugs and got no response after 6+ months.  Anyway.

Comment: Stumbled across this radar today: http://openradar.appspot.com/7316174 but given what the folks at Apple told me at WWDC, I suspect this would be resolved as "as designed." Not sure if I should accept my own answer ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I talked to some Apple folks today. The issue is definitely related to the animation that UITableView does when you insert new rows. This is the animation that happens to create new rows for cells, separate from the animation that is used when those rows are brought in via insertRowsAtIndexPaths.

Since the table-level animation creates new rows through a sort of "grow down" kind of thing, during the insert animation small amounts of many cells are considered visible and the table will call cellForRowAtIndexPath for them.

There doesn't seem to be any alternative implementation for this that works for all cases. The recommended solution for my case is to "lie": figure out what cells will exist on page after the animation and insert those. After that animation completes, insert the remainder of cells that won't show and the table won't call cellForRowAtIndexPath.

This requires implementing an object between the table view and the "real" data source that can "lie" to the table view about the number of rows in the table for the duration of the animation. Painful, but that's apparently what has been done in similar cases.

Comment: "a sort of "grow down"" - It sounds like you use the UITableViewRowAnimationTop or UITableViewRowAnimationBottom. You could try with the -right, -left or -fade animation instead, so not all cells are visible at the beginning.

Comment: Nope. This is not the cell animation. This is table-level animation (confirmed with Apple) and occurs even when you use UITableViewRowAnimationNone: the table still animates the cells in, at least in the case where there are no rows in the table to start, just the empty placeholders. The only way to disable this is turn off animations at the UIView level but then you're pretty much back to reloadData.

Comment: I ran up against this problem *AGAIN* today, forgot all about this post, re-Googled it, and jeez..  Why isn't there a fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what I did was to declare an attribute called bMassiveLoad initialized to false.
Before I do the 'massive load' I set it to true and the first thing I do in the cellForRowAtIndexPath was to check for that attribute.
At the end of the 'maseive load' I set it to false again and call reloadData...

I know that it is not a beautiful answer, but it helps me.

Comment: This is basically what I did too. An instant reloadData beats hanging the UI for half a second while the table tries to alloc/init a hundred more table cells.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by combining a few answers from here:

set the massive load boolean as needed as suggested by pocjoc

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            massiveLoad = YES;
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

and reload the visible rows when it ends

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    if (massiveLoad) {
        massiveLoad = NO;
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView calls the relevant delegate and data source methods immediately after a call to insertRowsAtIndexPaths to get the cells and other content for visible cells.  This is regardless of whether or not animated is set to YES or NO.

See the discussion [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38)

If you only want the tableView to update the visible cells, then just update your dataSource and call [tableView reloadData].

Comment: My issue is that it's calling cellForRowAtIndexPath for cells that are not visible, at least once the insert animation is done. (And I'm not sure what animated:YES/NO you're talking about.)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there may be a different way to go about this, but what I have found is that if you have existing cells in the visible range (for example, if you have 10 cells visible at all times and you initialize the tableView with 10 blank cells), when you add new rows, the extra rows are not called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

So, what to do about it.  This is how I went about fixing this.  When I created the tableView, I added cells to the visible region.  They were blank.  Then, when I inserted new rows, I only added index paths for the extra rows (i.e. if I have 10 visible rows and want to add 50 rows, including the visible rows, I only added 40 since the first 10 already exist).  This of course leaves you with 10 blank cells.  At this point, you can use:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [myTableView indexPathsForVisibleCells];
[myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

This selects your 10 visible blank cells and reloads them with the new information you have passed in (I assume you load data into an array for this part).  You will need to add a little logic to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method such as:

```
if (![myDataArray count]) {
    // create a blank cell;
} else {
    // add context to your cells as you want;
}
```

This should do the trick for you and only load the cells you have showing on the screen

Comment: I need to add cells. Not all will be visible.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I'm sorry for the confusion.  I will edit my answer to something that should help with that instead

Comment: I don't really need to update anything. I just want to insert, say, 50 rows but only get cellForRowAtIndexPath called on the 10 that show up. Are you suggesting calling reload* instead of insert*? I haven't tried it (yet), but that sounds like asking it to reload rows that don't exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were saying the opposite, that you have a bunch of rows already but only wanted to update the ones that are visible.  So you want to add a bunch, but only show a few?

Comment: I'm just trying to get normal cell rendering within the context of insert. When you do a reloadData, the table view only calls cellForRowAtIndexPath for the rows on the screen. When I insert rows, it calls cellForRowAtIndexPath for every row I insert, whether they're showing or not. That's too expensive.

Comment: Seems like you could add a test to see if a cell is visible in cellForRowAtIndexPath (using visibleCells property of UITableview) and only do the (expensive) processing if it is.

Comment: Well, it's still going to create too many cells. And if those cells ever get scrolled into view and they're crippled ...

Comment: I just wrote some code that creates an array of index paths and inserts them into a tableView when you click a button (I know your implementation is different, but should yield the same results theoretically).  I was able to replicate what you're talking about, so I'm going to mess around with it to see if I can stop it.  I'll be sure to udpate you if I find something useful

Comment: I sort of found a work around, so I am going to udpate my original answer to tell you what I did

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the behavior you describe is correct, but `UITableView` has got two methods: `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) that are meant to optimize redrawing (so that animating is done only at the end, otherwise they are done one by one and this could possibly produce the call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

Now, I am not sure if this could help you, but perhaps you can give this a try...

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I am doing this in a begin/end pair. Doesn't seem to make any difference, though.

Answer (score 0):

For swift you can try this

```
self.mainTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.mainTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.mainTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(self.mainTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.mainTableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score -1):

The UITableView will request the visible cells by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and it can reduce the processing time when there are many cells, ex 1k cells, and reduce spent memory by reusable cell mechanism. If you need to process all cells, then you should implement a custom method to re-process your source data, and then call `[tableView reloadData]` to update the UI.